# Missing spaces in ToC due to nicematrix and tocloft incompatibility

Tags: tocloft, incompatibility, nicematrix

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\chapter{The chap one}

\section{The sec one}

\section{The sec two}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    \CodeBefore
    \tikz\draw[red,line width=0.5pt] (2 -| 1) -- (2 -| 2);
    \Body
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `\CodeBefore` everything works fine.

Comment: My contents does not look like yours.

Comment: @polyn Note that the issue is not actually an incompatibility: the problem still shows if you remove `tocloft`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a small bug in `nicematrix` version 5.15 (2021/04/25): in some cases it adds an `\ExplSyntaxOn` to the `.aux` file, but it doesn't add the matching `\ExplSyntaxOff`, so spaces are ignored from that point onwards.  The issue should be fixed shortly, meanwhile you can add this patch to the preamble of your document (it will error when `nicematrix` is updated, then you should remove the patch):

```latex
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{nicematrix}{2021/04/26}
  {\PackageError{}{Patch no longer needed! Delete these lines!}{}}
  {\AfterEndEnvironment{NiceTabular}{%
    \immediate\expandafter\write\csname @mainaux\endcsname{\ExplSyntaxOff}}}
```

Here's the full example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\IfPackageAtLeastTF{nicematrix}{2021/04/26}
  {\PackageError{}{Patch no longer needed! Delete these lines!}{}}
  {\AfterEndEnvironment{NiceTabular}{%
    \immediate\expandafter\write\csname @mainaux\endcsname{\ExplSyntaxOff}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The chap one}

\section{The sec one}

\section{The sec two}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    \CodeBefore
    \tikz\draw[red,line width=0.5pt] (2 -| 1) -- (2 -| 2);
    \Body
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

As explained by Phelype Oleinik, this is a bug in `nicematrix`. I have done the correction and uploaded a new version of `nicematrix` (v 5.15a of 2021-05-06) on CTAN to solve that problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.